# Mongoose giving mpromise deprecation warning despite bluebird?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bluebird, next.js

I am constantly getting the following error while compiling my Node-Mongoose (NextJS) app:

> DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise
>   library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead:
>   http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

I already have the bluebird promise engine and can't figure out anything else I'm missing out on. My server file has the following declarations (among others, of course):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bluebird = require('bluebird');

mongoose.Promise = bluebird;
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_PATH, {
  useMongoClient: true,
  promiseLibrary: bluebird
});
```

And my model file has the following:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
```

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tired `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; ` before `mongoose.connect(...)` ?

Comment: I am using bluebird promise library instead and yes it's before the mongoose.connect() method as shown in the question. I don't want to use the native promise library.

Comment: I would go with ES6 Promises because it is absolutely going to fulfill everything you need for promises coming out of Mongoose.